# Perl subroutine to return all files recursively in a directory

Tags: perl

I am a newcomer to perl, while I can write code to print all file names in a directory in perl, I am not sure how to write a subroutine which will return the same to its caller function

Comment: [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File::Find)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [File::Find](http://p3rl.org/File::Find) module:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Find;

sub get_all_files {
    my ($dir) = @_;
    my @files;
    # Use $File::Find::name instead of $_ to get the paths.
    find(sub { push @files, $_ }, $dir);
    return @files
}

my $dir = shift;
my @files = get_all_files($dir);
print "$_\n" for @files;
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It seems to return directories as well, how can we get rid of that?

Comment: find(sub{if(-f $_){push @files, $_ }}, $dir);
    Figured it out. 
    Thanks!

Comment: @AvinashKumarPandey See my answer

Answer (score 4):

Try this
You want to search the file into directory simply use `File::Find` module. Or else you should create recursive subroutine to do it.

```
my $path = "/home";
find($path);
sub find{
    my ($s) = @_;
    foreach my $files (glob "$s/*")
    {
        if(-f $files)
        {
            print "$files \n";
        }
        elsif(-d $files)
        {
           find("$files")
        }

    }
}
```

Here `-d` used to check if the content is a directory. `-f` used to check content is a file.

First pass the name of the directory into the find subroutine. Then get the value by using $s variable, [glob/*](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) list the all files in the path. Then iterate the loop for the particulary directory files. If files exists it comes in the `if` block if folders exist it comes in to the `elsif`. Then the folder name goto the subroutine again and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Learn to find stuff in the documentation.

Start with "perldoc perlfaq" and you will find:

```
   perlfaq5 - Files and Formats
```

Then look at "perldoc perlfaq5" and search for "directory". You will find:

**How do I traverse a directory tree?**
       *(contributed by brian d foy)*

```
   The File::Find module, which comes with Perl, does all of the hard work to traverse a
   directory structure. It comes with Perl. You simply call the "find" subroutine with a
   callback subroutine and the directories you want to traverse:

       use File::Find;

       find( \&wanted, @directories );

       sub wanted {
           # full path in $File::Find::name
           # just filename in $_
           ... do whatever you want to do ...
       }

   The File::Find::Closures, which you can download from CPAN, provides many ready-to-use
   subroutines that you can use with File::Find.

   The File::Finder, which you can download from CPAN, can help you create the callback
   subroutine using something closer to the syntax of the "find" command-line utility:

       use File::Find;
       use File::Finder;

       my $deep_dirs = File::Finder->depth->type('d')->ls->exec('rmdir','{}');

       find( $deep_dirs->as_options, @places );

   The File::Find::Rule module, which you can download from CPAN, has a similar interface,
   but does the traversal for you too:

       use File::Find::Rule;

       my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                                ->name( '*.pm' )
                                ->in( @INC );
```